# To output a string without whitespce

Tags: python, python-2.7

My program:

```
def string_splosion(str):
    j=1
    c=len(str)
    i=0
    s=''
    while(i<c):
        s=s+(str[:i+j])
        i=i+1
        print s


print("Enter a string:")
s=raw_input()
string_splosion(s)

Sample input:Code
Expected output:CCoCodCode
My output:
Enter a string:
code
c co cod code
```

Could anyone please explain me how to remove the space and get the expected output **CCoCodCode** for **Python2.7.12**

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: My python execution gives the output you want in the final line: **CCoCodCode**.  Just move the **print** to after the while loop, instead of inside it.

Comment: I've tried your code with both Python 2.6.6 and 3.5.2; neither inserts the spaces.

Comment: I think you are adding a space to 'Code ' when you type it in

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are printing each iteration separately. Though you can get your example to work by changing the logic a little bit, this is an easy job for Python magic:

```
>>> s = 'Code'
>>> ''.join(s[:i+1] for i in range(len(s)))
'CCoCodCode'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
def string_data(str):
  result= ""
  for x in range(len(str)):
    result = result + str[:x+1]
  return result

string_data('code')
```