# Why doesn't the loop work as it be programmed?

Tags: python

While I tried to execute the following code, I faced some problem in loop iterations and couldn't figure out what's the problem might be.

```
def string_splosion(s):
    """Takes a non-empty string s like "Code" and 
    returns a string like "CCoCodCode"
    """
    for i in range(len(s)):
        return s[i] * (i+1)

print(string_splosion('Code'))
```

Comment: Please print the output

Comment: `return` returns from the function. That means no more of the function will be executed. You are always exiting the loop on the first iteration.

Comment: It's easier to do this with a simple list comp: `''.join([s[:i+1] for i in range(len(s))])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To output a string without whitespce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749377/to-output-a-string-without-whitespce)

Answer (score 3):

you leave the function after the first return.
I think this would be the right solution

```
def string_splosion(s):
  result = ''
  for i in range(len(s)):
      result += s[:i]
  result += s
  return result
```

Answer (score 3):

if you have return inside in a loop the loop is raning only for one time.

```
def string_splosion(s):
    """Takes a non-empty string s like "Code" and 
     returns a string like "CCoCodCode"
    """
    a=''  ## empty String
    for i in range(len(s)):
        a += s[0:i] +s[i]  ## this is beter way  to do this "CCoCodCode"
    return a               ## out of the "for" loop

print(string_splosion('Code'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
def string_splosion(s):
    return ''.join(s[:i+1] for i in range(len(s)))

print(string_splosion('Code'))
```